# Polynomial resultants restricted to intervals

Tags: polynomials, resultants

The resultant of two polynomials, $R(f,g)$, is a polynomial in the coefficients of $f$ and $g$, and has the property that $R(f,g) = 0$ if and only if $f$ and $g$ share a common root (possibly in an algebraically closed extension of the underlying field). In this question I am mainly thinking of polynomials having real coefficients, with real and/or complex roots.

I am wondering whether there is a kind of resultant which detects whether $f$ and $g$ share a common root, but restricted to a smaller domain, such as an interval, or perhaps the unit disc or a strip in the complex plane. Specifically, is there a kind of resultant method such that $\tilde R(f,g) = 0$ if and only if $f$ and $g$ share a common root $z$ such that $a < \Re(z) < b$, so that $\tilde R$ "ignores" any common root occurring outside this domain?

The problem at hand also has connections to real root counting in an interval, for which there are various methods. Two examples are Sturm's method and Budan's theorem, which count sign variations in polynomial sequences evaluated at the end points of the interval. A third approach is Hermite's method, which can count real roots $x$ according to whether $h(x) > 0$ or $h(x) < 0$, for some polynomial $h$, and is based on computing the signature/inertia of a symmetric Hankel matrix built using $h$. However, all three of these methods require some kind of *counting* process. As such, they do not easily lend themselves to elimination  methods (e.g., when the coefficients of $f$ and $g$ are themselves polynomials, say in the variable $y$). The roots of the normal resultant, $R_x(f,g)$, can locate precisely the $y$ value for which the counts/signatures change, but the normal resultant also produces many "spurious" zeroes corresponding to shared roots of $f$ and $g$ that occur outside the interval of interest (including those at infinity), which in my application I am wanting to ignore.

Does such a "resultant restricted to an interval" method exist? I suspect the answer is in the negative, but would really appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: An intentionally ridiculous answer:  $\tilde R(f, g) = 0$ if $f$ and $g$ share a root in the desired range, and otherwise $\tilde R(f, g) = 1$.  Clearly that's not what you want, but what *do* you want?  An obvious desire is to have something polynomial in the coefficients of $f$ and $g$, but I imagine it's pretty easy to prove that such a thing cannot detect the placement of zeroes as finely as you like; so what's allowed?

Comment: An ideal situation would have $\tilde R(f,g)$ be a polynomial in the coefficients of $f$ and $g$, though as you say, I suspect this is impossible. In my application, the coefficients are polynomials in $y$, and I'd like for $\tilde R(f,g)$ to be a function in $y$ that is as smooth as possible.

Comment: Impossibility of polynomiality in the coefficients of $f$ and $g$:  consider $\tilde R_x(f(x + t), g(x + t))$, which would then be polynomial in $t$.  Your condition would require that this be $0$ for $\lvert t\rvert$ sufficiently large, hence identically, even if $f$ and $g$ shared a common root in a restricted range.

Comment: The same argument shows the impossibility even of analyticity in the coefficients.  Something like $\tilde R(f, g) = \oint \frac1{f(z)^2 + g(z)^2}\mathrm dz$ over a suitable circle passing through $a$ and $b$, maybe?

Comment: Intriguing - there may be problems if a shared root occurs near/at the boundary of the disc, though I'd be happy to set out an assumption excluding that scenario (indeed, the original problem statement is somewhat ill-posed in this scenario anyway).